# Wildcard in URL (mod_alias or mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, mod-alias

I need to have URLs such as `mydomain.com/whatever`, where "whatever" can be any arbitrary string, all call the same php file where it sorts out what to display (or displays a 404).  However, I want files and other php files to work normally (anything that is otherwise aliased, or that actually exists in the file system).

A simple `AliasMatch /* myphpfile.php` (after all the other Aliases in httpd.conf) works fine on my own setup, but on a production server, the wildcard alias sends all the other php files to `myphpfile.php`. I'm not sure what else might be confusing things.

Technically the `whatever` string will be alphabetic and lower case, so it can filter for that, but all attempts I've made with regex's haven't been successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these rules (you need **mod_rewrite**):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteRule ([a-z]+) /myfile.php [L]
```

1. Place in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some tweaking may be required.
2. This will rewrite (internal redirect) all NON-EXISTING single-lowercase-word requests to `/myfile.php`, where using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` script can determine which URL was called and decide what to do (routing).
3. This will work for URLs like `/whatever`, but will do nothing for `/what-ever`, `/hello/pinky`, `/hello123`.

Comment: Thanks, although it looks like the production server doesn't have mod_rewrite so if there is any way to do it with mod_alias alone, that would be awesome.

Comment: @rob Unfortunately I do not know how it can be done with mod_alias. I recommend contacting your hosting company (or wherever your production server is) to enable it (mod_rewrite is so widely used, then I see no benefits having this disabled -- unless it is very cheap hosting where they have hundreds of sites on a single server).

Comment: It's a client's server, which they have pretty locked down.  If I can do things without bugging the IT guy (and waiting for him to get around to it), it's always better. :)  But thanks, I'll go ahead and tell them they need this, and use your solution.